# C - Pass multiple function addresses as parameters in a variadic function

Tags: c, function-pointers, memory-address, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a function that will take the first n integers and a variable number of functions and build a table that has the number as "i" in the first column and "function(i)" in the others.

But I cannot seem to be able to pass the addresses of my functions to the table generator because I get an access violation error. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef float(*f)(float);

// Some examples of f-type functions.
float square(float x) { return x*x; };
float root(float x) { return sqrt(x); };
float timesPi(float x) { return x * 3.14; };

// Display a table with first colon being the numbers from 1 to n, 
// then the other columns to be f(i)
void table(unsigned int n, unsigned int nr_functions, ...)
{
    va_list func;
    va_start(func, nr_functions);

    for (float i = 1; i <= n; i += 1)
    {
        printf("\n%6.0f |", i);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nr_functions; j++)
        {
            f foo = va_arg(func, f);
            printf("%6.3f |", foo(i));
        }
        va_end(func);
    }
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    table(5, 3, &square, &root, &timesPi);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For the example above

```
table(5, 3, &square, &root, &timesPi);
```

I want to get back

```
1   |   1.000 |  3.140 |
2   |   1.141 |  6.280 |
3   |   1.732 |  9.420 |
4   |   2.000 | 12.560 | 
5   |   2.236 | 15.700 |
```

Comment: The `va_start()` should be inside the outer loop, so that when you use `va_end()` you can restart using the argument list.

Comment: If `n` and `nr_functions` are 5 and 3, you try to get 15 arguments out of the `va_list`.

Comment: Why oh why are you using a *floating point type* for the loop index? Do you ever expect to loop 5.23 times? Integers can be easily converted to floating point values.

Comment: As for your problem, you show the results you *want* to get, but what result do you *actually* get?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm using a float for the loop index because this is part of a bigger problem, where I need to go from value to value in a floating point step, so in my real problem, I would have something like `for(float i = A; i <= B; i += interval), where A,B and interval are all float types.

Comment: Beware of floating point increments and terminating conditions.  If you add 0.01 to 0.00 one hundred times, there's a good chance that the result is not 1.00 (or, at least, it won't be 1.0000000).  You'd be better off defining the range and increments in terms of integer arithmetic, and scaling to get the actual value you want.  See Wikipedia on [Floating Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf), referenced in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reuse the variable section of the argument list, which means you need the `va_start()` and `va_end()` in the right places — inside the outer loop:

```
void table(unsigned int n, unsigned int nr_functions, ...)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        va_list func;
        printf("\n%6.0f |", (double)i);
        va_start(func, nr_functions);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nr_functions; j++)
        {
            f foo = va_arg(func, f);
            printf("%6.3f |", foo(i));
        }
        va_end(func);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you're marching off the end of the list, except that you called `va_end()` inside the loop, leading to goodness only knows what damage.

Note that the loop should use integer arithmetic — with a consequential change to the `printf()` — here I cast the value, but changing the format to `%6d` would also be sane (possibly better, in fact).

With this function, I got the output:

```
 1 | 1.000 | 1.000 | 3.140 |
 2 | 4.000 | 1.414 | 6.280 |
 3 | 9.000 | 1.732 | 9.420 |
 4 |16.000 | 2.000 |12.560 |
 5 |25.000 | 2.236 |15.700 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't think about having to reuse the parameter list.

Comment: Easily made mistake.  You wrote a nice question with good code — well done, and welcome to Stack Overflow.